# How to get a client context for App in provider-hosted Apps?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I use a provider hosted Apps, so need to work with an App Web and Lists.

Could anybody provide a code snippet to get ClientContext() of the App?

Can I do something like this?

```
Uri appWeb = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(appWeb, HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this blog http://www.greggalipeau.com/category/sharepoint-2013/apps/sharepoint-provider-hosted-apps-tips-and-tricks-series/

Comment: @RobertLindgren, Thanks a lot! It's a very helpful site for me!

Comment: Seemed to be! Good luck!

Comment: @Warlock if you found a solution you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the context of host web and app web to use SharePoint lists and libraries from your tenant and app as well. **Contexttoken** is mostly used in low-trust provider hosted app. In low-trust provider hosted app, you have to use [Azure](https://portal.azure.com) to host your web application. Azure is providing **SPAppToken** in url, by getting that you can get authentication token for app. **SPHostUrl** and **SPAppWebUrl** are also provided in url. You can get that from url and use that urls to get context.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx) you can get some reference about basic SharePoint Provider hosted app.

Some Links for reference

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/09/24/introducing-sharepointcontext-for-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps.aspx
- http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Getting-the-Client-Context-from-Claims-Aware-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013

Answer (score 1):

To get clientcontext for app web, you can check the code snippet below:

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPAppWeb())
{
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
    clientContext.Load<ListCollection>(lists);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```